# how can i Connect my one computer's file system with other in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ftp, server

I am using ubuntu 12.04 for some reasons i want to connect my local file system with other computer through ftp (filezila). I want to know is it possible or not . If yes then what is the procedure.I was looking for a filezila server . But after searching I went to know that this is only a window system.thanks

Comment: filezilla server I think it's windows only. Although, you can still run a vanilla ftp server and use filezilla ftp client. You may try something like this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

In order to do an FTP transfer, you need one server and one client. You can run the server on either machine, and the client on the other. The relationship is symmetrical, so if you want to transfer a file from machine A to machine B, you have 2 choices...

1. Run an FTP server on machine A, sit at machine B, start its FTP client and do an FTP GET operation.
2. Run an FTP server on machine B, sit at machine A, start its FTP client and do an FTP PUT operation.

As Ubuntu has an FTP server built-in, and Windows doesn't, I would suggest you run the FTP server on Ubuntu and the client on Windows.

So, in summary, I would run the built-in FTP server on Ubuntu, and the Filezilla client on Windows, or the built-in Windows FTP command-line client if you don't want to install any software.

Another option altogether, rather than constantly transferring (i.e. copying)  files between machines every time you want them, you could just `share` a directory on your Windows machine by right-clicking on it and setting `Sharing Options` and then, on the Ubuntu machine, use Samba to *map* the drive. That way you would not have to *move/transfer* files between machines all the time and worry about keeping them in sync - instead there would be a single version of the files on your Windows machine and the Ubuntu machine could directly read and write the same set of files whenever it wanted to.